# Refactoring out parts of a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model in app/models/user.rb. My User class has a lot of operations that are related to an external service, Intercom. Right now i have a bunch of methods like `register_intercom_user`, `update_intercom_data`, `ping_intercom`, etc. All of these are related to the User object.

I have a few options:

1. Create a mixin with these methods (easiest option). But then i'm polluting my User namespace.
2. Create a intercom.rb file in my lib/ dir with a `def new(user)`. This is a pain though since it's far away from the User class and doesn't imply the coupling.
3. Create a app/models/user/intercom.rb with a `class User::Intercom; def new(user)...`. Seems more right since it shows a coupling to the User model, but i havent seen this pattern in other projects.

Am I not thinking of something? What's the right pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for Concerns (in Rails4 or with a little config in Rails3) or Service Objects.

[This article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) has more ideas. I'd also suggest Ryan Bates' excellent Railscasts Pro episode #398.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with external services, there are usually some kind of a gem for that. You could either do the same thing, build a tiny gem dealing with your methods and include it in your gemfile as local gem.

Or you could simply "simulate" a gem by adding code in you lib directory.

The basic idea is to imply less "coupling". You `intercom` module / gem should not care about your `User` model.

Comment: My Intercom class actually does need access to many attributes of my User object -- there is coupling. I feel like a gem would be inappropriate in this case.

Comment: can't you extract what you need from the User model ? maybe someday you'll want another model to deal with your intercom external service.